# Is it possible to move several pages at once in pagetree in edit-mode?

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

In Windows you can Ctrl + Select multiple files, then drag and drop them or use the context menu.

Is there a similar function in EPiServer 6 R2? If not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: Found this, installed the module, but it does not appear amongst my gadgets. The post is from 2009 so maybe the module is for EPiServer 5 and not compatible with EPiServer 6 R2? http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/RuwenJin/Dates/2009/11/Gadget-Multi-Move-and-delete-multiple-pages/

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to drag & drop and put the pages yo want below a temp page with a comfortable placement.
Then move the temp page to the new location and drag & drop again.

As you've found there are also some plugins you can use but they're usually checkboxlist based and not integrated neatly into the page tree (I think).